# Malloc multiple connected structs in order to seperate scopes in a type checker

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to create a struct called `Block` that is connected to another struct called `Scope` that is yet again connected to another struct called `Vars`. The reason for this is because I am trying to write a Type Checker and need to make sure that the values that are assigned to a variable are of the same type.

So the best way I can think of is just to create a `Block` that can setup multiple `Scopes` that are supposed to collect all the variables inside a `{...}` block, when we reach the end, pop that block and end up in the previous one, simple enough..

Well, this is what I got

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "main.h"

struct Vars{
    char *var;
    int type;
};

struct Scope{
    struct Vars *vars;
    int num_of_vars;
};

struct Block{
    struct Scope *scope;
    int num_of_scopes;
};

void
newScope(struct Block *block)
{
    block->num_of_scopes++;
    block->scope = realloc(block->scope, sizeof(struct Scope)*block->num_of_scopes);
    block->scope[block->num_of_scopes--].num_of_vars = 0;
}

void addVarToScope(char *var, int type, struct Block *block)
{
    block->scope[block->num_of_scopes--].num_of_vars++;
    if(block->scope->num_of_vars == 0)
    {
        block->scope[block->num_of_scopes--].vars = malloc(sizeof(struct Scope));
    }
    else
    {
        block->scope[block->num_of_scopes--].vars = realloc(block->scope[block->num_of_scopes--].vars, sizeof(struct Scope)*block->scope->num_of_vars);
    }
    block->scope[block->num_of_scopes--].vars[block->scope->num_of_vars--].var = malloc(10);
    strcpy(block->scope[block->num_of_scopes--].vars[block->scope->num_of_vars--].var, var);
    block->scope[block->num_of_scopes--].vars[block->scope->num_of_vars--].type = type;
}

int
main()
{
    struct Block *block;
    block = malloc(sizeof(struct Block));
    block->num_of_scopes = 0;

    newScope(block);
    addVarToScope("123456789", 0, block);

    printf("%s\n", block->scope->vars[0].var);

    return 0;
}
```

The reason for all the `block->num_of_scopes--` bs is because it is supposed to work as a stack, I am only interested in the scope I am in and when I leave it I intend to free that space, since I then know it is ok (or throw an error if type checking fails). As you can see this became insanely verbose and complex very quickly, even in this smaller test file and not together with my parser also. The code above generate the error

> main: malloc.c:2539: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top
> (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE &&
> prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) ==
> 0)' failed. [1]    102422 abort (core dumped)  ./main

I have never seen this error before and have a hard time making sense of it. I have through gdb traced it to the reallocation in the function `addVarToScope`, but in my mind everything should be ok..

Do anyone know what the problem is and what I should do to fix it? Also (and maybe more important), is there a better way of doing this? Have spent days now trying to get this to work and I can not figure out a better/more clean way of doing it.

Comment: If you are building a hierarchy to check variables and type, why not order a bit closer to the way things are specified in the C standard `UNIT->SCOPE/BLOCK->VARS`. Where each translation unit can contain multiple code blocks (scopes) where vars can be introduced at any level within the unit?

Comment: That is what I intend to do, for example the prog `void main(){int a = 0; {int a = 1;}}`, then the code I have written should create 2 scopes and make sure that each level in its own scope fulfill the type. I may have misinterpreted what you meant.

Comment: Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
block->scope[block->num_of_scopes--].num_of_vars = 0;
```

`block->num_of_scopes--` evaluates to the *current* value of `block->num_of_scopes` and then decrements it.

So not only are you accessing one element past the end of the array the first time you do this, you end up decreasing this value into the negative with subsequent uses which access memory before the start of the array.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change all instances of `block->num_of_scopes--` to `block->num_of_scopes-1`.

In addition to this, `block->scope` is uninitialized the first time you pass it to `newScope`.  You need to set it to NULL when you first allocate space for `block`.

There is a similar problem with the `vars` member of `scope`.  You never enter the `if` part of `if(block->scope->num_of_vars == 0)` because you increment `num_of_vars` right before this line.  Do this *after* the `if` block.

Comment: Omg I am an idiot and you are an angel! Can finally go to sleep with peace of mind, thank you!